# Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the base object and not any of the properties

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have an class, Loans and I have an instance of it in my ViewModel.

I bind to multiple properties in Loans, like

```
loan.amount;
loan.name;
```

Etc.  I only raise `INotifyPropertyChanged` on loan itself, and the rest of the properties don't raise it.  IE

```
ViewModel{
loan { get; set { notifypropertychanged("loan")}
```

Everything I read says this shouldn't work, but it does...in fact, all of loans properties are binding properly and updating property.  I always thought you have to raise notifyproperty changed on each and every property, and can't just do it at the main object.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is working the way it should be. When you raise the property change, binding framework goes and get the updated value for the property.

Here when you are raising the property change on property of custom type (`loan`) in your `VM`, binding framework will get the updated value of `loan` and will hit getter of each and every property of 'loan' bound on the UI.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess the reason not to do that would be to limit updating all your properties after one update.  And to lock it down to only the single property you are updating.  Am I getting this?

Comment: offcourse, if there is change in just one property there is no need to raise the property change on whole object. But if your object instance is changing, then you just need to raise property on the object and not on each and every property

Answer (score 0):

No, that will work fine. You're specifying the full path to the property so anything that changes along that path will cause the binding to refresh. It also works if you do something like this:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding loan}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding amount}" />
</StackPanel>
```

In this case you're not specifying the full path in the TextBlock binding but its parent is bound to a property that does change notification and again it will inform its children if it sees there's been a change. Where you don't get change notification is if you do something like the above and keep loan the same but change amount.

Bear in mind there are different times when change notification is applied. If your UpdateSourceTrigger is set to "PropertyChanged" and you want updates to be applied the instant a value changes then yes, you have to apply it to each and every child member. If it's LostFocus then they'll all get done in one go once the focus is lost irrespective of whether or not they support change notification.

Answer (score 0):

The change notification only works when setting the loan object, not on its properties.

loan.amount = 123;

This uses the [loan] **Getter** and then then [amount] **Setter**.

If you need to listen form the parent object then you could set the loan as a private variable and expose the loan properties from the ViewModel

```
ViewModel
{
   private Loan _loan
   public decimal loanAmmont 
   { 
        get { return _loan.amount; }
        set 
        { 
            _loan.amount = value;
            notifypropertychanged("loan")
        }
    }
}
```

Or add the change notification to the loan properties and register to their change from the parent object

```
ViewModel
{
   private Loan _loan;
   public Loan loan; 
   { 
        get { return _loan; }
        set 
        { 
            _loan = value;
            _loan.PropertyChanged += NotifiyLoanChanged;
        }
    }

    void NotifyLoanChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // invoke my events to ViewModel listners
        notifypropertychanged(e.PropertyName);
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx